# Cover time of a box by SRW in $\mathbb{Z}^2$?

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

I am wondering can we say something about the cover time $T$ for a box, eg. $[-n,n]^2\cap \mathbb{Z}^d$, by the simple symmetric random walk on $\mathbb{Z}^2$ starting from zero?

For example, the expected time, the variance, or some scale $a_n$ such that $T\leq a_n$ with high probability?

(I tried search on web but found nothing. Maybe I am not searching with the correct things, but...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

"Cover times for Brownian motion
and random walks in two dimensions":  Annals Math 160 (2004), 433-464,
By Dembo, Peres, Rosen, Zeitouni.

See Theorem 1.4